# SlackBotでファイルが削除できない

Tags: python, slack

pythonで一定期間が過ぎるとファイルを削除するというslackのbotを作っていたのですが、botのトークンを使ってファイルを削除しようとすると、
`{'ok': False, 'error': 'cant_delete_file', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': ・・・}}`
といったレスポンスが返ってきました。SlackのAPIを見るとファイルは削除できるようになっているらしいのですがなぜでしょうか。回答いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。
実行環境
OS: Mac OS sierra
言語: Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

botのトークンを作成したユーザが`メンバー`権限で管理者権限を持っていないと、他人のファイルは[削除できません。](https://get.slack.help/hc/ja/articles/218159688-%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)
Slack APIの[テストページ](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.delete/test)で削除を試した際に下記のレスポンスが出る場合は権限を昇格してください。

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "cant_delete_file" 
}
```

もし手動では削除できてbotでは削除できない場合は、トークンなどの隠すべき情報を除いたpythonのコードや設定方法などの詳細な情報を追加すると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。